# MSSQL - Error while executing a procedure in a transaction - Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentClientRequest state

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I implemented a stored procedure in Microsoft SQL Server. And I am trying to execute this procedure in a transaction within an API using mssql.

When I am executing my procedure alone (outside a transaction in my API) everyting works fine but when I put it in a transaction I have this error :

> RequestError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentClientRequest state

This is my code :

```
app.post('/api/...', async function (req, res, next) {
    // Pool
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(databaseConfiguration);
    await pool.connect();

    const transaction = await new sql.Transaction(pool);

    // Transaction Begin
    transaction.begin(async (err) => {
        try {
            // Error checks
            if (err) throw new Error(err);
            // No error keep going
            // Create request
            const request = new sql.Request(transaction);
            // Input
            request.input('user', sql.VarChar, req.body.user);
            request.output('id', sql.Int);
            // Execute Procedure
            await request.execute('myProcedure', (error, result) => {
                // ... error checks
                if (error) throw new Error(error);
                // No error keep going
                console.dir(result);
            });
            // await fs.rmdirSync(dir, { recursive: true });
            transaction.commit((tErr) => tErr && next('transaction commit error'));
        } catch (error) {
            transaction.rollback((tErr) => tErr && next('transaction rollback error'));
            next(`unknown error inside transaction : ${error}`);
        }
    });
});
```

Does any one have any idea about my mistake ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Which line does the error occur on? Add `console.error(error)` in your catch block so you can see where the error occurs.

Comment: Hello I added the console.log(error) and the error ```Error: RequestError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentClientRequest state``` occur on the line ```if (error) throw new Error(error);``` inside my request.execute(). However this error do not occur when request.execute() is outisde my transaction. Thanks by advance for any help

Comment: Remove the callback from .execute and `await` it instead

Comment: You were right thank you so much for the help ! So the solution was to write ```await request.execute('myProcedure')```